# WordPress plugin to output a certain category on content page tweak help

Tags: blogs, wordpress

I'm using WordPress plugin [Category Page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page2cat/) to display the most recent 5 posts from a certain category on a regular content page (not the blog page) of a website.

Right now the plugin is limited to display the post title linked to the post page. This is a video blog type site and I need the plugin to display the post title (as it does now) with the video as well. Probably just telling the script to show the content would work but I don't know how to tweak it.

This is the section of the script that is outputting the post title:

```
function page2cat_content_catlist($content){
global $post;
    if ( stristr( $content, '[catlist' )) {
        $search = "@(?:<p>)*\s*\[catlist\s*=\s*(\w+|^\+)\]\s*(?:</p>)*@i";
        if  (preg_match_all($search, $content, $matches)) {
            if (is_array($matches)) {
                $title = get_option('p2c_catlist_title');
                if($title != "") $output = "<h4>".$title."</h4>"; else $output = "";
                $output .= "<ul class='p2c_catlist'>";
                $limit = get_option('p2c_catlist_limit');
                foreach ($matches[1] as $key =>$v0) {
                    $catposts = get_posts('category='.$v0."&numberposts=".$limit);
                        foreach($catposts as $single):
                        $output .= "<li><a href='".get_permalink($single->ID)." '>".$single->post_title."</a></li>";
                        endforeach;
                    $search = $matches[0][$key];
                    $replace= $output;
                    $content= str_replace ($search, $replace, $content);                    
                }
            $output .= "</ul>";
            }
        }
    }
return $content;
}
```

If anyone has any advice or knows how to help thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is in $single->post_content in your example. Add it to the `$output`:

`$output .= "<li><a href='".get_permalink($single->ID)." '>".$single->post_title."**<span class='video'>".$single->post_content."<span>**</a></li>";`

Comment: Something to keep in mind: updating the plugin will break the present functionality.